# iOS open google maps route

Tags: ios, maps

I'm wondering why this is not working for cause there are a lot of examples on the web which exactly show the syntax how the maps app could be opened and a route can be displayed from a start to an endpoint.

But anyway, here is what i'm trying to do:

In my app i have a button and on when it's pressed, the maps app should be opened and the route from A to B should be displayed. So far so good.
The only thing is, my starting point is my actual position in x/y coordinates and my end point is an adress.
So i tried to form the url like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Mariahilferstraße+123+1000+Wien&saddr=43.213646,11.491927
```

And the the code that the maps app should open is this:

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 NSMutableString *url =  @"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Mariahilferstraße+123+1000+Wien&saddr=43.213646,11.491927";
 [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

The maps app does not open....

Can anybody see a problem here and can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw: when i copy the url in my desktop browser is works!

Comment: seems that the "daddr=Mariahilferstraße+123+1000+Wien" doesn't work, you should get the lat/long for that address using a reverse geolocator

Comment: thx, but have you an example or link where this is explained?

Comment: I found the real problem, seems like the maps app doesn't accept Mariahilferstraße, if you change it to Mariahilferstrasse it works, try with my answer, maybe the geocoder get a lat/long for Mariahilferstraße

Comment: Wow it really seems that the "ß" was the problem! Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the geocoder (Is a simple geocoder, not reverse as I commented, reverse is for getting an address form lat/log)

```
[fgeo geocodeAddressString:@"Boston, MA"
            completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){

             // Make sure the geocoder did not produce an error
             // before continuing
             if(!error){

                 // Iterate through all of the placemarks returned
                 // and output them to the console
                 for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){
                     NSLog(@"%@",[placemark description]);
                 }
             }
             else{
                 // Our geocoder had an error, output a message
                 // to the console
                 NSLog(@"There was a forward geocoding error\n%@",
                         [error localizedDescription]);
             }
         }
   ];
```

[tutorial](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1830485&seqNum=3)